# How to perform one operation on each executor once in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, weka, partitioning

I have a weka model stored in S3 which is of size around 400MB.
Now, I have some set of record on which I want to run the model and perform prediction.

For performing prediction, What I have tried is,

1. Download and load the model on driver as a static object , broadcast it to all executors. Perform a map operation on prediction RDD.
   ----> Not working, as in Weka for performing prediction, model object needs to be modified and broadcast require a read-only copy.
2. Download and load the model on driver as a static object and send it to executor in each map operation.
   -----> Working (Not efficient, as in each map operation, i am passing 400MB object)
3. Download the model on driver and load it on each executor and cache it there. (Don't know how to do that)

Does someone have any idea how can I load the model on each executor once and cache it so that for other records I don't load it again?

Comment: Starting with Spark 2.4 there's a Java interface `ExecutorPlugin` that allows custom `init()` and `shutdown()` > https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24918

Answer (score 41):

You have two options:

### 1. Create a singleton object with a lazy val representing the data:

```
    object WekaModel {
        lazy val data = {
            // initialize data here. This will only happen once per JVM process
        }
    }
```

Then, you can use the lazy val in your `map` function. The `lazy val` ensures that each worker JVM initializes their own instance of the data. No serialization or broadcasts will be performed for `data`.

```
    elementsRDD.map { element =>
        // use WekaModel.data here
    }
```

**Advantages**

- is more efficient, as it allows you to initialize your data once per JVM instance. This approach is a good choice when needing to initialize a database connection pool for example.

**Disadvantages**

- Less control over initialization. For example, it's trickier to initialize your object if you require runtime parameters.
- You can't really free up or release the object if you need to. Usually, that's acceptable, since the OS will free up the resources when the process exits.

### 2. Use the `mapPartition` (or `foreachPartition`) method on the RDD instead of just `map`.

This allows you to initialize whatever you need for the entire partition.

```
    elementsRDD.mapPartition { elements =>
        val model = new WekaModel()

        elements.map { element =>
            // use model and element. there is a single instance of model per partition.
        }
    }
```

**Advantages**:

- Provides more flexibility in the initialization and deinitialization of objects.

**Disadvantages**

- Each partition will create and initialize a new instance of your object. Depending on how many partitions you have per JVM instance, it may or may not be an issue.

Comment: Are you sure about #1? I am getting serialization errors with it. Also, what do you do if the data initialization depends on runtime parameters?

Comment: There shouldn't be any serialization happening with approach #1. If there is, it's likely that you're referencing an intermediate object in your RDD methods. Regarding your question about initialization, it is indeed more difficult to control. Your runtime parameters would need to also be available statically (e.g. via System properties or configuration files). Singleton initialization isn't Spark-specific though; it's a Scala topic.

Comment: Can you do the same in Java?

Comment: With respect to this disadvantage, `Less control over initialization. For example, it's trickier to initialize your object if you require runtime parameters.`.  This is exactly what I am trying to achieve. Do you have any examples or have you seen this done? I am making a call to an external system to get the database connection configs. So ideally, I do not want to call the external system on each executor. I just asked this question which is very similar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47241882/spark-object-singleton-serialization-on-executors

Comment: One possible way to initialize your DB connection is via System properties (e.g. `System.getProperty("db.host")`)

Comment: @DiaKharrat can you please provide a solutin in python? if a want to load a huge file (8gb) pretrained embedding file on each executor once, how we can do it?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what worked for me even better than the lazy initializer.  I created an object level pointer initialized to null, and let each executor initialize it.  In the initialization block you can have run-once code.  Note that each processing batch will reset local variables but not the Object-level ones.

```
object Thing1 {
  var bigObject : BigObject = null

  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    val sc = <spark/scala magic here>
    sc.textFile(infile).map(line => {
      if (bigObject == null) {
         // this takes a minute but runs just once
         bigObject = new BigObject(parameters)  
      }
      bigObject.transform(line)
    })
  }
}
```

This approach creates exactly one big object per executor, rather than the one big object per partition of other approaches.

If you put the *var bigObject : BigObject = null* within the main function namespace, it behaves differently.  In that case, it runs the bigObject constructor at the beginning of each partition (ie. batch).  If you have a memory leak, then this will eventually kill the executor.  Garbage collection would also need to do more work.

Comment: this will call `new BigObject` multiple times if your `spark.executor.cores` is greater than 1. the lazy approach protects against concurrent initialisation.

Comment: @Dan do you mean `lazy var bigObject ...`?

Comment: @Dale, you code is technically not thread-safe, since multiple executors can initialize your global object if they run concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what we usually do

1. define a singleton client that do those kind of stuff to ensure only one client is present in each executors
2. have a getorcreate method to create or fetch the client information, usulaly let's you have a common serving platform you want to serve for multiple different models, then we can use like concurrentmap to ensure threadsafe and computeifabsent
3. the getorcreate method will be called inside RDD level like transform or foreachpartition, so make sure init happen in executor level

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by broadcasting a case object with a lazy val as follows:

```
case object localSlowTwo {lazy val value: Int = {Thread.sleep(1000); 2}}
val broadcastSlowTwo = sc.broadcast(localSlowTwo)
(1 to 1000).toDS.repartition(100).map(_ * broadcastSlowTwo.value.value).collect
```

The event timeline for this on three executors with three threads each looks as follows:

[image: Event Timeline for Stage 1]

Running the last line again from the same spark-shell session does not initialize any more:

[image: Event Timeline for Stage 3]

Answer (score 0):

This works for me and it's threadsafe if you use singleton and synchronized like shown below

```
object singletonObj {
  var data: dataObj =null
  def getDataObj(): dataObj = this.synchronized {
     if (this.data==null){
        this.data = new dataObj()
     }
     this.data
  }
}

object app {
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      lazy val mydata: dataObj = singletonObj.getDataObj()
      df.map(x=>{ functionA(mydata) })
   }
}
```