# Spark Streaming connection pool in each JVM

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, connection-pool

In my spark streaming app, I have many I/O operations, such as codis, hbase, etc. I want to make sure exactly one connection pool in each executor, how can I do this elegantly?
Now, I implement some static class dispersedly, this is not good for management. How about centralize them into one class like xxContext, some what like SparkContext, and need I broadcast it? I know it's good to broadcast large read-only dataset, but how about these connection pools?
Java or scala are both acceptable.

Comment: i think this anwser can solve your question.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015777/how-to-perform-one-operation-on-each-executor-once-in-spark][1]

Answer (score 1):

## `foreachPartition` is best fit

Sample code snippet to it

```
val dstream = ...

dstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>

  //loop through each parttion in rdd
  rdd.foreachPartition { partitionOfRecords =>

    //1. Create Connection object/pool for Codis, HBase

    // Use it if you want record level control in rdd or partion
    partitionOfRecords.foreach { record =>
      // 2. Write each record to external client 
    }
    
    // 3. Batch insert if connector supports from an RDD to external source
  }

  //Use 2 or 3 to write data as per your requirement 
}
```

[Another SO Answer for similar use case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41953960/1592191)

check this: [Design Patterns for using foreachRDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd)

Comment: DB Connection can not be serialized with state(transient). So, it's recommended to create/maintain connections(or pools) at executor level. Usually per executor one connection does well, Other side database need to serve **executor number of connections** in parallel. All the connections will be independent as executors are independent. So, I am not sure about the idea of centralizing is great.

Comment: But I want to maintain a connection pool for each JVM to reduce cost. My confusion is how to centralize them.

Comment: Each executor is JVM process. As mentioned in the code you can create db connection pool at **point 1** in the sample code for each JVM.

Comment: But in spark streaming, will this(foreachRDD) be called multi-times?

Comment: Yes, foreachRDD calls multiple times(If DStream has multiple rdds). Every rdd will have partitions those are exists at worker machine. check this: [Design Patterns for using foreachRDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd)