# Creating singleton object in Spark for each executor

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, singleton

I've quite a similar problem described here:
[How to perform one operation on each executor once in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015777/how-to-perform-one-operation-on-each-executor-once-in-spark)
I followed the first approach in the first answer but still got a Serialization problem.

What I want to do is, I have queries like a tuple of (sourceVertex, targetVertex) and send these to executors and executors will return to me a shortest path. For this I'm using jgrapht.

When I implement like this

```scala
class ShortestPath(graph: SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph[Node, DefaultWeightedEdge], 
bc: Broadcast[SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph[Node, DefaultWeightedEdge]]) extends Serializable {

  def calculateShortestPath(vertexRDD: RDD[Node]) = {

    val result = vertexRDD.map(vertex => {
      val dijkstraShortestPath: DijkstraShortestPath[Node, DefaultWeightedEdge] 
                = new DijkstraShortestPath[Node, DefaultWeightedEdge](bc.value)
      val distanceIn = dijkstraShortestPath.getPath(vertex, Node(4, 1, true)).getWeight()
      distanceIn
    })
    result.collect().foreach(println(_))
  }

}

object ShortestPath {
  def apply(graph: SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph[Node, DefaultWeightedEdge], 
bc: Broadcast[SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph[Node, DefaultWeightedEdge]]): ShortestPath = new ShortestPath(graph, bc)
}
```

Everything is okay
But the problem is I think I'm creating `dijkstraShortestPath` object for each task, am I right?

My aim is to create this object for each executor and use it for each task on that executor.

The link that I gave says create a Object with lazy val, instantiate your think here then use it RDD map function. I implement that solution like this:

```scala
object Dij {
  lazy val dijsktra = {
    val graph = GraphCreator.createGraph()
    val dijkstraShortestPath: DijkstraShortestPath[Node, DefaultWeightedEdge] = new DijkstraShortestPath[Node, DefaultWeightedEdge](graph)
    dijkstraShortestPath
  }
}
```

and used in ShortestPath class

```scala
    val result = vertexRDD.map(vertex => {
      val dijkstraShortestPath = Dij.dijsktra
      val distanceIn = dijkstraShortestPath.getPath(vertex, Node(4, 1, true)).getWeight()
      dijkstraShortestPath
    })

    result.collect().foreach(println(_))
```

but then I'm getting serialization error thank says
`- object not serializable (class: org.jgrapht.alg.shortestpath.DijkstraShortestPath, value: org.jgrapht.alg.shortestpath.DijkstraShortestPath@2cb8e13b)`
which is right, when i look implementation there is no Serializable.

And another question is if it is not Serializable then how my first implementation worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is an unintended error in your second snippet.

The first function given to a map returns a weight (presumably a `Double`?) the second returns a `DijkstraShortestPath` which is not serializable. This explains why the two snippets behave differently.

Comment: you are right, there was my mistake. When I change to return value to double value it worked